# How can I change the balance or volume of each speaker independently while playing audio?

Tags: audio, titanium, appcelerator

How can I change the balance or the volume of each speaker independently while playing audio in Titanium Appcelerator? I know that changing the balance is doable in Android directly, but I didn't see this feature in the Appcelerator API.